# API for DOL jobs site data

Tags: labor

Is there an API available for the job listings that appear at [Seasonaljobs](https://seasonaljobs.dol.gov/)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this gives access to the above but it might be worth taking a look at: https://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide/